# Hadwiger number of total graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph, and let $T(G)$ be its [total graph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239806/total-chromatic-number-and-total-clique-number). The *Hadwiger number* $\eta(G)$ is the maximum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K_n$ is a minor of $G$.

Is there an example of a graph $G$ such that $\eta(T(G)) > \Delta(G) + 2$ (where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree)?

Comment: Isn't this asking about Hadwiger conjecture for total graphs? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: It is easy to construct graphs of maximum degree three with arbitrarily large clique minors, so examples are easy to find even without looking at the extra edges in the total graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph $T(G)$ contains as a subgraph $L(G)$, the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of $G$.

Abrams and I [constructed](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/60/ajc_v60_p314.pdf) a $K_{9k + 1}$ minor in the graph $L(K_{5k+2})$.

Comment: I found that the The Australasian Journal of Combinatorics butchered their SSL settings with a self-signed certificate. It's safe, just don't give it your Social Security Number.